# Using Integrals With Internal Rate of Return?

Tags: discounting

I'm taking a Calculus 2 course this Fall, and for my honors project, I will be using the IRR function. My professor is requesting that I figure out a way to use an integral with the IRR.

The cash flow scenario being modeled has first period/outgoing/negative cash flow (NPV variable), and one final terminal positive cash flow (CFx), with each period between the first period and final period being 0.

I've taken the NPV function: $NPV=\sum _{n=0}^N\:\frac{CFx}{\left(1+IRR\right)^x}$ , and as we just have one positive terminal cash flow, I've removed the summation and solved for the IRR (with the terminal year=x), with the function becoming $IRR=\left(\frac{CFx}{NPV}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-1$

As the IRR function is not cumulative, taking an integral of the IRR function as defined would be meaningless.

Does anyone have an idea as to how an integral could be used for the project?

I really appreciate any assistance that's provided.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would probably be to consider a bond that pays coupon *continuously*. This can be justified as a useful approximation for very frequent (ex. daily) coupon payments, and would allow you to use an integral instead of a summation. The value of such a bond would be: $NPV = \int_0^T \frac{100c}{(1+IRR)^t} \text{d}t + \frac{100}{(1+IRR)^T}$